# Animating clip-path in safari not working

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, clip-path

I am working on a simple css animation of the `clip-path` property, using the basic `inset` shape to create a sweep effect. This works well in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari.

If I resize the window of Safari, or do something else forcing a redraw, it does render the current state of the animation. So it seems to be an issue of the animation not being redrawn properly.

I believe you need to prefix clip-path with my `-webkit-`, and i have done so.

I am using the latest version of Safari: 12.1.1

Here is a fiddle illustrating the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/vwth9mjr/

I would expect the animation to work as it does in Chrome and Firefox.

Safari shows no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `.pane` css from fixed to absolute seems to works:

https://jsfiddle.net/d32bm6jo/5/